# Xml file generator in java

Tags: java, xml

I want to make a java swing application from where i can generated xml file which hold same data,and generated number of file will be decided by user.My xml file holds xml schema and my xml file struture is looking like this

```
<transaction>
  <xs:schema id="transaction" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
    <xs:element name="transaction" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
      <xs:complexType>
        <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
          <xs:element name="id">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="name" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="sn" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="data">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
          <xs:element name="productData">
            <xs:complexType>
              <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="dateTime" type="xs:dateTime" minOccurs="0" />
                <xs:element name="key" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" />
              </xs:sequence>
            </xs:complexType>
          </xs:element>
        </xs:choice>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
  <id>
    <name>smith</tli>
    <sn>1234567</sn>
  </id>
  <data>
    <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
    <key>book</key>
  </data>
  <productData>
    <dateTime>2011-06-24T17:08:36.3727674+05:30</dateTime>
    <key>game</key>
  </productData>
</transaction>
```

I am new in java if some one give some code snipes help, it will be more helpful for me.

I want to generate xml files which hold the xml schema which is given in my example xml.

Comment: look at dom4j - http://dom4j.sourceforge.net/  Try writing some code and come back if you are having problems

Comment: @GreenDay - While I always liked dom4j better than JDOM, unless there is a specific need, I'd strongly recommend sticking to a standard API like JAXP - instead of tightly binding the code to a particular implementation like dom4j.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In java you use the [JAXP](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPIntro.html) to work with XML. You use [DOM](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JAXPIntro5.html) related classes to generate the xml. Below is a small example of using JAXP to create XML.

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class WriteXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("company");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);

        // staff elements
        Element staff = doc.createElement("Staff");
        rootElement.appendChild(staff);

        // set attribute to staff element
        Attr attr = doc.createAttribute("id");
        attr.setValue("1");
        staff.setAttributeNode(attr);

        // shorten way
        // staff.setAttribute("id", "1");

        // firstname elements
        Element firstname = doc.createElement("firstname");
        firstname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("yong"));
        staff.appendChild(firstname);

        // lastname elements
        Element lastname = doc.createElement("lastname");
        lastname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mook kim"));
        staff.appendChild(lastname);

        // nickname elements
        Element nickname = doc.createElement("nickname");
        nickname.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("mkyong"));
        staff.appendChild(nickname);

        // salary elements
        Element salary = doc.createElement("salary");
        salary.appendChild(doc.createTextNode("100000"));
        staff.appendChild(salary);

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("C:\\file.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: I did this type of code but I cannot generate xml file with schema which is given in my desired xml.

Comment: Thanks for your help but i didnot found any solution to generate xml file with schema. I did this type of code but I cannot generate xml file with schema which is given in my desired xml.

Comment: @saba schema is also a xml so u can generate that one too

Comment: yeap,but I didnot find any help in internet how to do that is it like to just adding node like xml.Is it possible without hard code it means schema will be generated automatically with my xml?

Comment: @saba it is just like adding nodes in xml.

Comment: like .Net is it possible schema is generated automatically with xml file in java.

Comment: or I will define schema and xml file is generated automatically in java may be i think wrong i donot know actually.

Comment: I used you're code and it works like a charm. The thing is, how do I get it to "newline" each element?

Comment: Hi Aravind, which approach would be the best performance wise? To avoid using so much memory ? Isn't it better to use simply a StringBuilder?

Answer (score 0):

I have an older post on my personal blog that outlines several different ways of generating XML in Java:  http://blogger.ziesemer.com/2007/06/xml-generation-in-java.html

Basically, some common options to work with are JAXP, DOM, SAX (kind of a hack for generation, but it works), StAX, XSLT, or the XML binding options (JAXB) - which I did not cover in my post.

Since you already have a XML schema to work with, JAXB may work well for you.  Otherwise, I'd probably go with StAX as one of the newer and efficient APIs.

Comment: actually I read about this API but maximum are prefer jaxb api because it is easy to generate xml schema and xml file and processing power is high is it true?

Comment: I am also did not generate the schema with this xml file.

Comment: I read your blog it really helpful there are so many things which i really donot know but i did not found any solution to write a xml file with schema.If you share some knowledge it is helpful for me.

Comment: Still I didnot understand how o generate this xml file with schema using jaxb can u have any idea.I listen that .net can generate xml file with schema can java do that.

Comment: @saba - You're looking for JAXB.  Please follow the tutorial at http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/1.6/tutorial/doc/JAXBUsing.html - which specifically covers creating Java mapping classes from an XML schema.

Comment: Hi ziesemer, which approach would be the best performance wise? To avoid using so much memory ? Isn't it better to use simply a StringBuilder?

Comment: @DiegoRamos - Read my post as to why I'd avoid a StringBuilder.  StAX will be the most memory-efficient option, at least of those listed above.  Actually, with StAX plumbed directly to a file or a network stream, it can consume little-to-no memory - even less than StringBuilder.